# Algorithm for finding double subwords of given word

Tags: algorithm

Subword U of given word V is double, when It's in form u=ww, for example "abab" is a double subword of "acdababx" but "cdab" is not.

I need an algorithm that checks if given subword U of word V is double. V can be preprocessed in linear time, but answer for any particular U should have constant time complexity, becouse there will be many U's for every V. U is given as an interval,for example if V = "acdababx",
interval [3..6] corresponds to subword "daba".

example input and output:

V = abbacbacca

U =

- [1 4] --> No
- [3 8] --> Yes
- [5 8] --> No
- [8 9] --> Yes
- [1 10] --> No

This is not a problem from any current contest.

Comment: so `u -> ww` is guaranteed to only have `w` twice?

Comment: Or more interesting ... how to find all double substrings in a string?

Comment: @Argote: by writing u=ww I meant that u is some word appended to itself. @belisarius: finding all double substrings in a string can be easily done in O(n^2) time, but its too slow here, as n can be large.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, what I meant is whether the times it will be repeated for it to be valid is 2 times or 2 OR MORE times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one algorithm which claims to mark the endpoints of all the double words (or as it is commonly known in literature, tandem repeats) in a suffix tree of the input word (which can be constructed in O(n)) time. Of course, since I don't have full access to the article, I am not sure if it will satisfy the O(1) query time.

The paper is: [Linear time algorithms for finding and representing all the tandem repeats in a string](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0022000004000364)

Hope that helps.